# How to see an object's full type name in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

For example, having the following code:

```
// This is hidden from my eyes
String str = "abc";

// I can see this
System.out.println(str);
```

i'd like to point to `str` in the last line and see that it's type is indeed `java.lang.String` (not just `String`). Where can I find this information (I am sure Idea knows it, as it can show the object's members correctly)?

Comment: This seems like plain old Java... why is it tagged as scala?

Comment: @pablo-fernandez, because I want this for Scala actually, but I believe this is done the same way with Java and there are more Java developers than Scala developers to answer the question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hover the mouse over the identifier with the ctrl key held down, and you will see a tooltip containing the full type name.

Comment: In Kotlin, this works for me on usages of the variable, but not at the declaration. Given that Kotlin declarations can have implicit types, this is a pain!

Comment: is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: CTRL + Q is the Quick documentation lookup and will include the type

Comment: @Brad unfortunately, it doesn't. At least no in version 2021.3.1 CE

Comment: My original answer and the Ctrl-Q one from Brad both still seem to be correct. I'm on 2021.2.4 UE.

Answer (score 31):

If you place the caret inside the variable you want to identify and press

> CTRL + SHIFT + P

a small popup will show the type like so:

[image]

If you place the caret inside an expression, Idea will first ask what part of the expression you want to identify.

Answer (score 1):

The control-[hover over the identifier] thing works for Scala, but I don't use it very often.  Most of the time I want to know the type of an expression, not just a symbol.  [select an expression] followed by control-shift-P is the way to get that.

The command is called "expression type", so if those keyboard shortcuts aren't working for you, hit ⌘-shift-A and type in "expression type".  It'll tell you your current shortcut for that command.

Closely related:  I'll often tell Intellij to add type annotation to a binding.  If your cursor is on *fnord* in a line like this:

```
var fnord = Monoid[Flurbish].sharky.shark.shark(!snowball)
```

Hit option-return, and one of the things you can do is add type annotation.  If type annotation is already there, you can remove it, or if you've changed the type of the expression you can then have Intellij update the type annotation to the new one.  (The command is called "Add type annotation to value definition")

Answer (score 1):

`F1` key has worked for my Mac's community version: 2018.1.6

Answer (score 0):

[Ctrl]+[Alt]+T when the curser is inside the identifier. Also works for the return types of method invocations.

Comment: Currently, CTRL+ALT+T is the 'surround with' shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

In CLion variant you can see a variable's definition in a pop-up with Command + Shift + I (Command uppercase letter 'i') ("Inspect" in my head to help me remember it).

Answer (score 0):

In intelliJ you can directly jump to the type/class by pressing the keys CTRL+SHIFT and clicking with the mouse on the variable. That has the same effect as if you would ordinarily click with the mouse on the type along with key CTRL.